# Div tag is creating a gap in the middle of text

Tags: css, image, html

I am a newb to HTML and CSS and first time poster here. I looked all over for my issue and was unable to find a solution.

This is for the page: http://www.nursingassistantdegree.com/break-the-cycle-of-single-mom-poverty-by-earning-a-certified-nursing-assistant-degree/

Notice the sentence "Working Minimum Wage..." is broken up (in the HTML that is where the img div begins).  I would like to remove that space so the "minimum wage" is directly underneath the "assistant degree".  If you notice underneath the image the texts just flows nicely together.

Here is the CSS coding (note: I have adjusted all of the numbers of the borders and margins):

```
.picture { 
    background-color: #cee4fa;
    border: 3px solid #cee4fa; padding: 3px;
    font: 11px/1.4em Arial, sans-serif; align:right
}
.picture img { 
    border: 1px solid #cee4fa;
    vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.right { margin: 0.5em 0pt 0pt 0.8em; float:right; }
.left { margin: 0.5em 0.8em 0.5em 0; float:left; }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
".... you need to be in. Working <div class="picture right"  style="width:402px;">
<img src="http://www.nursingassistantdegree.com/wp-
content/uploads/2013/05/CertifiedNursingAssistantDegree.jpg" width="400" height="267"
align="right" alt="Certified Nursing Assistant Degree"/>Photo Courtesy of Felbry
College</div><p align="justify">minimum wage is never going....."
```

Any info you can offer would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra padding in p element:

Try to change it as:

```
.bodyconMiddleInnerLBoxThree p {
font: normal 15px/18px "Myriad Pro";
color: #37383A;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Tremendously, i spent hours on that haha.  I actually just posted a new help topic if you want to give that a try as well :-)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897917/reconfiguring-an-api-feed-to-match-from-another-page

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding: 10px` from `.bodyconMiddleInnerLBoxThree p`

Currently

```
.bodyconMiddleInnerLBoxThree p {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Change to

```
.bodyconMiddleInnerLBoxThree p {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```